# How to match computername to SSL cert on Windows Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server, windows, ssl, server

My aim is to install a signed certificate on my SQL Server 2019 running on Windows Server 2019.

I have installed the certificate correctly, using Lets Encrypt, and selected SQL Server to use this certificate. According to SQL Server instructions, for it to work however, the computername of this Windows Server 2019 must match the certificate exactly. In my case,`sql.companyname.com`. And I have tested this is correct on previous installs (pre-2019).

So I am running an AWS EC2 instance with a default ComputerName for example `EC2-123ABCD`. If I try and change it to `sql.companyname.com`, Windows says:

> Invalid computer name.

In fact it doesn't allow domain names at all. On previous versions of Windows Server, I was able to edit the registry key `ActiveComputerName`. And this use to work well. But whenever I do this on Server 2019, and reboot, it goes back to the previous computer name. If I update the `ComputerName` key as well, and reboot, it crashes the entire virtual server permanently as it fails to boot with a critical error.

So how do I match my SSL cert to computer name if windows doesn't even allow it, and registry hacks don't seem to work on Server 2019?

Edit: see answered below.

Comment: *According to Sql Server instructions, for it to work however, the computername of this Windows Server 2019 must match the certificate exactly.* What instructions say this (provide a link)? So long as the sql.companyname.com FQDN is registered in public DNS with an A record you should be able to connect using that name. If you're needing localhost connections to work as well you should be able to add a 127.0.0.1 mapping via the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file.

Comment: It’s a documented limitation. The ms sql service will fail to even start if the computer name does not match the sql cert. I will find the links and add them here. 

Sure the fqdn of the connection must also match. But that’s not the only requirement. I don’t understand how other people are getting past this issue??? Must be thousands of servers doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the computer name on your SQL server matches the name you wish to use for client connections. For example if client applications connect to “sqlsrv.cloudpeople.com.au” then the computer name should be sqlsrv. This name will also need to be registered as an A record on your public DNS name servers.